# ExtJS 6 Polar chart label renderer omitted when the same data set loaded

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have an [Ext.chart.PolarChart](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.chart.PolarChart.html) and to hide overlapped labels (for too small sectors) I use label renderer.

Everything works well, but I noticed that if I get the same data set from the server renderer is omitted and all labels are displayed. What could be the problem?

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27c8), just click "Set same data" (if you click "Set random data" after that, everything will work again).

Answer (score 0):

The label renderer gets omitted when the same data set is loaded because the series/labels get re-rendered only when there is an update in the store. I have made some changes to your code. You can check my comments and console to verify this.

I have also changed the **if-else** statement in the renderer function to make the code work.

Changed Code [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27in)

Comment: Thanks for asnwer! Yes, I understand that renderer is ommited when store is not updated, but the question is why hidden labes became visible? And I cant accept your solution because label "sticks" remains visible.

Comment: I understand that `display: 'none'` should be used to hide labels but It seems to be a bug in this version (couldn't find the release notes though.) It works in **Ext JS 6.5.0.775 - Triton**. I have updated the code.